# In python pandas adding age bands to dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm a novice and have figured out a fair bit on my on but was hoping someone could tell me how to add a column to the data frame that has an age band based on a date of birth in another column. For instance if: df.DOB.isbetween(1/1/2007,12/31/2012) then df['ageband']="0to5"

In excel I use a vlookup function for this. I've been trying to find a solution for hours. I was at least able to figure out how to get the True false flags...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to perform a given function on each value in a column.  I think something like this should work:

```
def get_ageband(value):
    ageband = None
    if value.isbetween(1/1/2007,12/31/2012):
        ageband = "0to5"
    return ageband

df["ageband"] = df.DOB.apply(get_ageband)
```

Comment: I'm surprised pd.cut doesn't work with this.  It would be nice to do `pd.cut(dates,['20070101','20121231'])` or something similar and pass in the bin labels.

Comment: Thanks. Now an even more basic questions - I'm using pandas.read_csv and it automatically defaults columns with blanks to strings. I tried to import into numpy first and specify data types but that's not working either. Seems like a simple problem that should have a simple solution. I'm struggling here... FYI- I took AP Comp Sci (Pascal) and (C++ 1-semester in College 12 years ago) and I'm an investment professional, not a real programmer but trying. . . Thank you so much!